# React Native Firebase Error [auth/-] An internal error has occurred. [ Json conversion failed ...] and [Handshake failed]

Tags: firebase, react-native

When I try to create a new account,  I'm getting following error on a MEMU emulator.

First, create a Firebase Project in https://console.firebase.google.com and download google-services.json . in Sign-in method of Authentication section Email/Password status is Enabled.
[firebase 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2gvc.jpg)

[firebase 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXRZw.jpg)

also in
android-> app->build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line
.....
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.planify"
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
```

Next, put json file in `android-> app`

[json add to react native project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxDTD.jpg)

after I run project and click a new account

```
 ERROR  [Error: [auth/-] An internal error has occurred. [ Json conversion failed! Failed to parse error for string [<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en>  <meta charset=utf-8>  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">  <title>Error 403 (Forbidden)!!1</title>  <style>    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}  </style>  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>  <p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>  <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser</code> from this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>] ]]
```

[Error in Memu Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EUQV.jpg)

[Error show in Node.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTeaK.jpg)

also, I manualy add a user in Authentication of project in console.firebase but when I click in Login button

```
[auth/unknown] An internal error has occured. [Handshake failed]
```

https://github.com/P-MBD/Filimo

android app  build gradle add `compileSdkVersion 33` also in

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.practice2"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        compileSdkVersion 33
        compileSdk 33
```

[image]

Comment: did you resolve it ? i'm facing similar issue @Parinaz

Comment: after search in internet add android-> app -> build.gradle add `compileSdkVersion 33` also in  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.practice2"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        compileSdkVersion 33
        compileSdk 33    still error. but I want to create a new project and try again.